# What does "Save up to 20 more" mean?

Tags: disney-magical-world

In some stores, such as the cafe or Daisy's shop, the bottom right corner says "Save up to 20 more".  I've tried tapping on it, but nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot]

What does it mean to save up to 20 more?  How can I get it?  Is it a per-store thing or would getting it for the cafe also get it for all the other stores?

Answer (score 1):

I think that means you can save up to 20 more recipe notes(which you can view in Recipes).

Comment: How does one get this 20 note savings?  I've seen it in multiple stores so would I need to acquire it for each store or is it something that is universal once acquired?

Comment: Well that's what I think...